# How to ignore first two columns of CSV file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a .csv file, that contains students names, students IDs, and many columns of grades and use that information to write lines in a listbox that look like this John --> 12345 --> 89.50, where the first value is student name, the second value is student id, and the third value is an average of the test scores.

I'm able to read the file and assign token[0] to name and token[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewaCA.png) to ID, I just can't figure out how to get the remain values (grades) from a string to a double, so that I can do the math to get the averages.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace McKensey
{
    //struct for students name, ID, grades
    struct Student
    {
        public string name;
        public string ID;
        public string grade;
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //feild to hold a list of GradeEntry
        private List<Student> gradeList = new List<Student>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //the ReadFile method reads thecontents of the .csv test and stores
        //it as Student objects in gradeList
        private void ReadFile()
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;     //to read the file
            string line;                //to hold a line from the file
            double grade;
            double total = 0;

            //creat a instance of the Student structure
            Student entry = new Student();

            //create a delimiter array
            char[] delim = { ',' };

            //open the .csv file
            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //open the selected file
                inputFile = File.OpenText(openFile.FileName);

                //read the files data
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //read the lines from the file
                    while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                        //tokenize the line
                        string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                        entry.name = tokens[0];
                        entry.ID = tokens[1];



                        gradeList.Add(entry);

                    }


                }
                //close file
                inputFile.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Opertaion Canceled.");
            }
        }
        private void DisplayInfo()
        {
            foreach (Student entry in gradeList)
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(entry.name + "-->" + entry.ID + "-->" + entry.grade);
            }
        }


        private void processButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadFile();
            DisplayInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you show your CSV file data? Also, is this question actually about ignoring the first 2 columns, or is it about parsing a string to a double?

Comment: So is your question about ignoring columns or converting string to double?

Comment: I'm not sure :/ if there is a way to convert only the grade columns of the CSV I guess I that I what I'm trying to do. Sorry I'm very new to programming.

Comment: in which part of the remaining values you want to do the grade? c?D?E?F?G?

Comment: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)

Comment: @Vijunav Vastivch I need to use columns C through AJ in the .csv file

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
IEnumerable<string> strCSV =
            File.ReadLines(@"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Book1.csv");

var results = from str in strCSV
            let tmp = str.Split(',')
                .Skip(2)  // skip the first two columns
                .Select(q => Convert.ToInt32(q))
            select new
            {
                Max = tmp.Max(),
                Min = tmp.Min(),
                Total = tmp.Sum(),
                Avg = tmp.Average()
            };

        var query = results.ToList();

        foreach (var q in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format("Maximum: {0}, " +
                              "Minimum: {1}, " +
                              "Total: {2}, " +
                              "Average: {3}",
                    q.Max, q.Min, q.Total, q.Avg));
        }
```

Comment: When I try that I get an error that says I cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'. on this line --> entry.grade = grade;

Comment: When I ran my program with you suggestion I got, for the first line "Alexander-->587285-->3.5" Now I just need to total all the columns of grades and then get the average.

Comment: this only converts the token in the 2 position. I need convert all of the remaining token to doubles, in order to find the average

Answer (score 0):

If the third column is your grade column, it is needed to be like this

```
 entry.name = tokens[0];
 entry.ID = tokens[1];
 entry.grade = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[2]);
```

**edit: I fixed the string to double conversion**

when we trace your code piece which reads file,

- Reading line with `line = inputFile.ReadLine();`
- Splitting line to the pieces

  - here you are transforming line string to array of strings with the delimiter ,
  - arrays start from position 0 goes until Length - 1 (your csv file has 7 colums so your array starts from 0 and ends at 6)
- then reads everyline with tokens[column_number]

**ATTENTION**

your code has two while conditions `while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)` which does not make sense. only 1 while condition is enough for reading single file. remove the outer while condition.

**EDIT**

you need to either change your Student.grade property to double and use `entry.grade = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[2]);` or keep it string and use `entry.grade = tokens[2]`

```
struct Student
{
    public string name;
    public string ID;
    public double grade; //this line has modification 
}
```

Comment: every column from the 3rd on is a grade column.

Comment: What has this answer got to do with the question?

Comment: I actually have 33 lines of grades. I just cut it off at 7.

Comment: @Enigmativity if you read question and comments, you will understand that the author of the question has little programming experience. I am trying to explain him how his code works and  how `entry.grade = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[2]);` gives him correct solution

Comment: well @MacieMcKensey the while loop in your code loops until  the end of your file. why do you have concern about it?

Comment: I am the author of the question :) I'll try that now.

Comment: I could not understand why proper and extensive  definition of a question leaded to downvote.  I am kindly asking comment for it. thank you

Comment: entry.grade = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[2]); give me the cannot implicitly convert type double to string.

Comment: check my post again, if you believe that this post is helpful to you. please consider to accept it as answer by pressing the green tick thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rest from Double into String then you can do it something like:

```
 entry.grade = double.Parse(tokens[2]).ToString() + ',' + double.Parse(tokens[3]).ToString() + ',' + double.Parse(tokens[4]).ToString() + ',' + double.Parse(tokens[5]).ToString() + ',' + double.Parse(tokens[6]).ToString();
```

You can wrap it with try catch if you want to handle the error.

Comment: what is the use of this? how does he make calculation with this?

Comment: there is no clarification to this `the remain values (grades) from a string to a double`. I'm just posting the whole remaining so the he can adjust which columns he wanted to be a grade.